# git merge confusion

Tags: git, git-merge

I just started using GIT yesterday and i was trying to do something but i think something went wrong somewhere . Let me explain my situation:

I started off with my working directory (master branch) looking like this

```
folder1
file1
file2
file3
```

I created another branch with the `$ git checkout -b X` command

After this , i went ahead and deleted all the files that were in the folder `rm -r *` and then added a few files in , so the working directory became so (this i think i wasn't supposed to do)

```
xFile1
xFile2
```

Then after some tests and after i arrived at the fact that the branch was stable .. i wanted to perform a merge and so i did

```
$ git checkout -b master
$ git merge X
```

Now , after the merge , my directory (folder1) got removed . What i actually wanted was to bring xFile1 and xFile2 into the master branch.

I'm so confused with this , please help!

Comment: Did you actually commit anything to branch X?

Comment: yes yes .. the xFile1 and xFile2 were committed to X

Comment: If you didn't commit the *removal* of those files, then there should be no problem. You must have also removed those files to produce the symptoms you're describing.

Comment: Oh i actually did commit the removal of the files :(

Comment: If you're new to git, I would highly reccomend having a browse through (at least) the first few chapters of the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book). It explains git concepts very well, and has a bunch of diagrams that greatly helped me to understand what was going on, and how to achieve things that I wanted to do with git.

Comment: @simont: I've looked at this book and it really is great :) In addition to that i've also looked at http://book.git-scm.com/index.html which is a pretty handy resource too . Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should have [rebased](http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html) instead of merging. The rebase is more of what you're trying to express - you have a good code **base** in `X`, and you want to add what's in `master` on top of what you put in `X`.

If you use `git rebase X` from `master` branch, it will play all the commits in `master` **on top of** `X`

Comment: Oh , i understand :) Let me quickly try that and get back to you

Comment: Hey @kelloti , i did the `rebase` and it worked fine except for when it applied the commit from X where i had deleted the `folder1` , so i'm losing out on that . Anything i can do about this ? :(

@meagar , please look at this ..

Comment: @Shrayas I think you're looking for the `-i` option for `git rebase` (interactive) http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html

Answer (score 1):

Part of your confusion looks like you assumed that merging ignored your delete operation.  In fact, when you deleted the files and committed that change, it remembered this.  Merging into master then replayed that delete.

Comment: Yes . I just realized that now :( So what would be the correct workflow? Isn't one supposed to delete files ? But what if my feature really doesnt depend on those files ?

Comment: @Shraya: If you want the files, don't delete them.  If you delete them by accident, use <code>git reset</code> or <code>git checkout</code> to retrieve them.

Comment: well the files are necessary for the `master` branch but not for feature `X` , right ? how about then ? i'm thinking i should've removed them by doing a `git rm` then?

Comment: @Shrayas:  How do you develop a product while deleting code that's not relevant to a specific feature?  How is removing existing features helping the overall product?

Comment: Yes , come to think of it .. that does make sense. Ok so how do fix this now? i need to checkout to say a branch `old` to the commit before the deletes happened , merge in the new changes from `X` to `old` and merge `old` back into `master` ?

Comment: @Shrayas: Use ***git log*** to list the revisions, then ***git checkout *hash* -- filename*** to get a copy of the file from a specific revision.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a commit on branch X before coming back to master? 
In case not , then it can always create mishaps in git.